# Please help me tweak this code...can't figure out what's breaking it! (Need to add links via jQuery)

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I think I've almost got it, but I'm newish to jQuery and must be overlooking what the problem is.

Here is my code.

```
// <![CDATA[

var root = null;

$(document).ready( function(){

    $.get( "/_assets/xml/sitemap.xml", 
        function( data ) {
            root = data;
            var pathname = window.location.pathname;

            var local_url = "*[url=" + pathname + "]";
            var currpage = $(root).find(local_url).attr("name");
            var parentEls = $(root).find(local_url).parents();

            var mapped = $(parentEls).map(function () { 
                  var element = $(this).attr("name");
                  var element_url = $(this).attr("url");
                  var element_wrap = $(element).wrap('<a href=' + element_url + '/>');
                  return element_wrap; 
                    })
                .get()
                .reverse()
                .join(" / ");

            $("#breadcrumb").append("<p>" + mapped + " / " + currpage + "</p>");

        } );
} );

// ]]>
```

Here is where I'm having trouble:

```
var mapped = $(parentEls).map(function () { 
                  var element = $(this).attr("name");
                  var element_url = $(this).attr("url");
                  var element_wrap = $(element).wrap('<a href=' + element_url + '/>');
                  return element_wrap; 
                    })
```

What I'm trying to do is wrap each element in an `<a>` tag and assign href=element_url. But I keep getting errors. Can anyone see a fix? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick stab at it:

```
var element_wrap = $(element).wrap('<a href="' + element_url + '" />');
```

The change is the double quotes - you were producing a string like this:

`<a href=http://somewhere.come />`

but you wanted

`<a href="http://somewhere.come"  />`

Answer (score 0):

There's another problem:

```
var element = $(this).attr("name");
```

returns a string, which you try to use as a selector... `$(element)`. I'm guessing that it's unable to find any tags to wrap.

You don't need that line at all. Just replace `$(element).wrap` with `$(this).wrap`

Comment: This eliminated the error but the links still aren't being applied.

Comment: Did you do what was suggested by Surreal Dreams as well? The two problems both need to be fixed

Comment: And another problem: $(this).wrap() returns the original element, not the wrapped one, so you want $(this).wrap(...).parent()